# In app subscription says "The item you requested is not available for purchase"

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-purchase, android-billing

1. I've created apk with BILLING permission and uploaded to production (Not published)
2. Created an yearly $0.99 subscription under in-app products (Activated).
3. Included license key in code.
4. Rebuilded signed apk and uploaded in alpha (Not rolledout).
5. Added tested email accounts.
6. Joined as tester with testing email account.
7. Waited alpha updated from google play doesnt worked. Installed alpha apk  manually.
8. Tried to launchPurchaseFlow with subscription with following code.

I'm using IabHelper.

```
//SKU_SUBSCRIBED is the product id of subscription. Which is double verified by me.
//RC_REQUEST = 10001
//payload = "mytesttoken"

mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(HomeActivity.this,
                        SKU_SUBSCRIBED, IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS,
                        RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

It's says

> The item you requested not available for purchase

What mistake I have done here ?

Comment: Is id of subscription identical in GooglePlay console and your app?

Comment: Yes, SKU_SUBSCRIBED is same as subscription id in Google play console

Comment: Is version of the app on your phone equals with the version of the app in GooglePlay alpha channel?

Comment: Ive uploaded same file in alpha and my phone. But i just saved alpha, didnt choose rollout.

Comment: You should do `Full rollout` in alpha

Comment: @DimaKozhevin Thank you very much, full rollout settled it. Can you add that an answer ?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, I will soon add this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do next steps:

- Check id of the subscription in GooglePlay console and your app. They must be identical.
- Check the version of the app on your phone and the version of the app in GooglePlay alpha channel. They must be identical.
- Release in the alpha channel should be as `Full rollout`

Comment: .. and official doc for others https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#draft_apps

Comment: You can release as Internal test track as well